# websocket in javascript - displaying error in console

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am very new to websocket and started working WS in javascript and thinking to integrate this websocket later with dojo.

This is my code

I am using MAMP as local server, I can access my localhost using 'http:// localhost' and http:// localhost:80

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost', 'json');
         connection.onopen = function () {
           console.log('Connection Opened');
         };
         connection.onerror = function (error) {
           console.log('WebSocket Error ' + error);
         };
         connection.onmessage = function (e) {
           if(e.data.indexOf("subProtocol")==-1)
             document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=e.data+"<br/>";
         };
         function sendMessage(msg){
           connection.send(msg);
         }
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>WebSocket Echo Client</h1>
      <button>
         Send Hello
      </button>
   </body>
</html>
```

I am getting the following ERROR in console
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200 client.html:4
WebSocket Error [object Event]

Thanks,
Mo

Comment: what are you using server side for your sockets?

Comment: I guess I am not using anything, because I dont know . This is my start up. Please guide me the flow

Answer (score 0):

in order for websockets to work, you'll need a server side mechanism to open sockets and support the communication.

some popular frameworks for this are [socket.io](http://socket.io/) (on node.js) and [signalR](http://signalr.net/) (on .net)

there is a nice primer [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/).

Comment: can you please direct me with working tutorial link. I am using websocket in javascript now.

Comment: what is the technology stack you're using?

Comment: I am using dojo, websocket with perl

Comment: have not used that one, but this seems like a good article http://showmetheco.de/articles/2011/2/diving-into-html5-with-websockets-and-perl.html